# Append two dimensional array on the right

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I am using this code to append a two dimensional array on the left:

```
static TElement[,] AppendColumnOnTheLeft<TElement>(TElement[,] before)
        {
            var after = new TElement[before.GetLength(0), before.GetLength(1) + 1];
            for (var i = 0; i < before.GetLength(0); ++i)
                for (var j = 0; j < before.GetLength(1); ++j)
                    after[i, j + 1] = before[i, j];

            return after;
        }
```

How to append the matrix on the right !? Could anyone help me to modify the code!

Comment: You'd just do `after[i, j] = before[i, j];` instead

Comment: @juharr are u sure for that ?

Comment: @kn1ghtx Why not?

Comment: The `j + 1` bit is making it copy the nth column in `before` to the n+1 column in `after` thus leaving the first column empty.  By just copying directly you'll leave the last column empty instead.  By empty I mean the default value of `TElement`.

Comment: @juharr thanks for your answer